# When my AI is in `WhilePatroling` Here it follows Spline Path with lag (freezes for a second and moves forward)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help with implementing Unity’s NavMeshAgent follow Unity Spline Path
When my AI is in `WhilePatroling` Here it follows Spline Path with lag (freezes for a second and moves forward)

When follows player that it works normally

Here is code for AI:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.Splines;

namespace MeenyAI.AIRuntime.Core
{
    public enum AIState
    {
        StartSearching,
        WhileSearching,
        StartPatrolling,
        WhilePatrolling,
        Following,
        StartWaiting,
        WhileWaiting
    }

    public class EnemyAICore : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform Target { get; private set; }
        public bool HasTarget { get; private set; } = false;

        private AIState currentState = AIState.StartPatrolling;
        private bool isTargetPointSet;

        [SerializeField] private NavMeshAgent agent;

        [field: Header("AI Settings")]
        [SerializeField] private LayerMask targetMask;
        [SerializeField] private LayerMask obstacleMask;
        [field: SerializeField] public float seeRadius { get; private set; } = 25f;
        [field: SerializeField] public float seeFOV { get; private set; } = 220f;
        [field: SerializeField] public float attackRadius { get; private set; } = 5f;
        [field: SerializeField] public float attackFOV { get; private set; } = 90f; 
        [SerializeField] private float lostTargetTime = 1f;
        [SerializeField] private float searchTime = 5f;
        [SerializeField] private float hideBehindDoorTime = 2f;
        [SerializeField] private float hideBehindCornerTime = 3f;
        [SerializeField] private SplineContainer patrolPathContainer;
        private SplinePath patrolPath;
        private float patrolTime = 0f;

        [Header("AI Loop")]
        public bool loopEnabled = true;
        public float loopWaitTime = 0.2f;

        private AIRoom lastRoom;

        private void Start()
        {
            InitializePatrolPath();
            StartCoroutine(AILoop());
        }

        private void InitializePatrolPath()
        {
            var pathTransform = patrolPathContainer.transform.localToWorldMatrix;
            List<SplineSlice<Spline>> splineSlices = new List<SplineSlice<Spline>>();

            foreach (Spline spline in patrolPathContainer.Splines)
            {
                splineSlices.Add(new SplineSlice<Spline>(spline, new SplineRange(0, GetSize(spline.Knots)), pathTransform));
            }

            patrolPath = new SplinePath(splineSlices);
        }

        private IEnumerator AILoop()
        {
            WaitForSeconds loopWait = new WaitForSeconds(loopWaitTime);

            while (loopEnabled)
            {
                GetTarget();

                Debug.Log($"Distance to target: " + agent.remainingDistance);

                switch (currentState)
                {
                    case AIState.StartPatrolling:
                        StartPatrollingBehavior();
                        break;

                    case AIState.Following:
                        FollowingBehavior();
                        break;

                    case AIState.StartSearching:
                        lastRoom = AIPlayerInformations.Instance.PlayerCurrentRoom;
                        StartSearchingBehavior();
                        break;

                    case AIState.StartWaiting:
                        TrollBehavior();
                        break;
                }

                yield return loopWait;
            }
        }

        private void StartPatrollingBehavior()
        {
            currentState = AIState.WhilePatrolling;
            StartCoroutine(WhilePatrollingBehavior());
        }

        private IEnumerator WhilePatrollingBehavior()
        {
            while (currentState == AIState.WhilePatrolling)
            {
                Vector3 position = patrolPath.EvaluatePosition(patrolTime);
                FollowTarget(position);

                while (!isTargetPointSet)
                {
                    if (agent.remainingDistance < 0.1)
                        isTargetPointSet = true;

                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
                }

                isTargetPointSet = false;

                patrolTime += (float)(0.005f * Time.deltaTime);
                if (patrolTime > 1f) patrolTime = 0f;
            }
        }

        private void FollowingBehavior()
        {
            if (Target != null)
                FollowTarget(Target.position);
        }

        private void StartSearchingBehavior()
        {
            currentState = AIState.WhileSearching;
            SearchRoom();
        }

        private void TrollBehavior()
        {
            currentState = AIState.WhileWaiting;
            StartCoroutine(TrollCycle());
        }

        private void GetTarget()
        {
            Collider[] foundColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, seeRadius, targetMask);

            if (foundColliders.Length != 0)
            {
                Transform target = foundColliders[0].transform;
                Vector3 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;

                if (Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, direction) < (seeFOV / 2))
                {
                    float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);

                    if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, direction, distance, obstacleMask))
                    {
                        HasTarget = true;
                        Target = target;
                        currentState = AIState.Following;
                    }
                    else
                        CantFindTarget();
                }
                else
                    CantFindTarget();
            }
        }

        private void FollowTarget(Vector3 position)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(position);
        }

        private void CantFindTarget()
        {
            if (currentState == AIState.Following)
                currentState = AIState.StartSearching;

            LoseTarget();
        }

        private void LoseTarget()
        {
            HasTarget = false;
            Target = null;
        }

        private void SearchRoom()
        {
            StartCoroutine(SearchTimerBehavior());
            StartCoroutine(SearchSubBehavior());
        }

        private IEnumerator TrollCycle()
        {
            WaitForSeconds waitForDoor = new WaitForSeconds(hideBehindDoorTime);
            WaitForSeconds waitForCorner = new WaitForSeconds(hideBehindCornerTime);
            WaitForSeconds waitUpdate = new WaitForSeconds(loopWaitTime);

            GoToRandomPointsInRoom(lastRoom.Doors);
            isTargetPointSet = false;

            while (!isTargetPointSet)
            {
                if (agent.remainingDistance < 0.1)
                    isTargetPointSet = true;
                yield return waitUpdate;
            }

            yield return waitForDoor;
            isTargetPointSet = false;

            GoToRandomPointsInRoom(lastRoom.Corners);

            while (!isTargetPointSet)
            {
                if (agent.remainingDistance < 0.1)
                    isTargetPointSet = true;
                yield return waitUpdate;
            }

            yield return waitForCorner;

            if (currentState == AIState.WhileWaiting)
                currentState = AIState.StartPatrolling;
        }

        private IEnumerator SearchTimerBehavior()
        {
            WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(searchTime);
            yield return wait;

            if (currentState == AIState.WhileSearching)
                currentState = AIState.StartWaiting;
        }

        private IEnumerator SearchSubBehavior()
        {
            WaitForSeconds waitUpdate = new WaitForSeconds(loopWaitTime);
            isTargetPointSet = true;

            while (currentState == AIState.WhileSearching)
            {
                if (isTargetPointSet)
                    GoToRandomPointsInRoom(lastRoom.Points);

                isTargetPointSet = (agent.remainingDistance < 0.1);
                yield return waitUpdate;
            }
        }

        private void GoToRandomPointsInRoom(Transform[] array)
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, array.Length);
            Transform point = array[randomIndex];
            FollowTarget(point.position);
        }

        private static int GetSize(IEnumerable toCount)
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach (var part in toCount)
            {
                count += 1;
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

I;m trying to make Unity NavMeshAgent follows Unity Spline Container Path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the occurrences of

```
while(!isTargetPointSet)
{
    if (agent.remainingDistance < 0.1)
    {
        isTargetPointSet = true;
    }
    else
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

should rather be replaced by a simple

```
yield return new WaitUntil(() => agent.remainingDistance < 0.1);
```

making it

- way less error prone than sharing the very same class field between multiple routine implementations
- way more readable & maintainable

An outer `yield` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77997631/7111561) would also not be required then because this one already yields for at least a frame.

Also in general you might want to redesign your state machine. It is pretty confusing to have all those class fields instead of proper return values and method arguments. Also you just hope/rely on that there will no concurrent routines running at the same time.

- You either want to stick to Coroutines

  In that case I would make sure each routine is

  - self contained. Not using class fields but parameters and local variables
  - exclusive. Your `while` conditions somewhat go into that direction but you should be completely sure there can only be one routine running at a time (e.g. by using `StopCoroutine` to interrupt any other active one)
- or if you have class level fields for everything anyway you could as well just stick to a plain `Update` based method calls instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should yield a single frame instead of `WaitForSeconds(0f);`.
Replace with

```
yield return null;
```

Also inside of the `WhilePatrollingBehavior`, you are not waiting any frames in your outer while loop.
Add the same `yield return null;` statement in there somewhere.

```
private IEnumerator WhilePatrollingBehavior()
{
    while (currentState == AIState.WhilePatrolling)
    {
        ...

        while (!isTargetPointSet)
        {
            if (agent.remainingDistance < 0.1)
            {
                isTargetPointSet = true;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        ...
        
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Without a yield statement, the while loop will just keep looping until the condition is false with no delay between loops causing freezing/lag.